# How to fetch records for certain days based on a timestamp using a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch records from every Saturday. I have a column **create_date** (timestamp) - 2016-06-22 07:20:22.220

The below query works for me for a single day.

```
 select * from table
  where create_date > '2016-06-04'
  AND creat_date < '2016-06-05'
```

But what if I want to fetch records for multiple days say - **2016-06-11**, **2016-06-18**, **2016-06-25**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DATENAME()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(v=sql.105).aspx) function for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATENAME(dw, create_date) = 'Saturday'
```

If you want to also restrict the range of `create_date` you can add a check in the `WHERE` clause for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATENAME(dw, create_date) = 'Saturday' AND
      create_date BETWEEN '2016-06-04' AND '2016-06-25'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use datediff per a refer date.
this sample is '2016-06-11'.

```
select * from table
 where datediff(d,'2016-06-11',create_date) in (0,7,14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATENAME` SQL function for this

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, create_date) = 'Saturday'
```